How can I use yaml file in pyspark code executing on EMR cluster?
In EMR cluster , I am running the pyspark code,which uses the yaml file, I am getting the path not found error.
I am using the following spark submit :
spark-submit --deploy-mode client --executor-memory 20G --num-executors 4 --executor-cores 4 --jars s3://stage/jdbc_driver/ojdbc8.jar --files s3://rxl-dev-stage/etl_script/constants.yml s3://stage/etl_script/main.py

And the following piece of code is executing :
with open("constants.yml","r") as f:
    constants=yaml.safe_load(f)

I also tried:
with open("/mnt/spark/work/files/constants.yml","r") as f:
     constants=yaml.safe_load(f)

But in both cases I am getting the  "such path not found error".
If any one could help me what should I look for?
Thanks.

If you can, use a python file with x = "x_string" and call the x assignment.
If you need to use a yaml file, you'll have to deal with finding the correct path per script you want to call from.
def _sanitize_path_for_windows(path):
    treated_path = path
    if os.name == 'nt':
        treated_path = "../" + path
    return treated_path

replace this path with your path
example path = "main_project_name/pipelines/datasources/data/"
replace the parts of the path in the below function
def find_data_path():
    if os.getcwd().split("/")[-1] == "main_project_name":
        location = "./data/"  # Running on Github Runner
    else:
        current_path = os.getcwd().split("/")
        come_out = "../"
        for i in range(len(current_path)):
            if current_path[-i] == "pipelines":
                come_out = come_out * i
                break
        location = come_out + "data/"
    location_sanitized = _sanitize_path_for_windows(location)
    return location_sanitized

